# How do I optimize these set of repeatable Javascript code with just number changes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a set of repeatable and similar code to open and close several modals. The modals can number up to a hundred as they will be generated via a cms and I have programmed it to use ids to call each modal with their own distinct content. These modals open when a text or anchor link is clicked and close when the background or close button is clicked. The ids used to label the texts, anchor link, and modals are all similar except that they have been suffixed with an index number of 1,2,3....,n.

Text 1 or Anchor 1 will open Modal 1. The modal-close-1 button or modal-bg-1 will close modal-1.
Text 2 or Anchor 2 will open Modal 2. The modal-close-2 button or modal-bg-2 will close modal-2.
Text 1 or Anchor 3 will open Modal 3. The modal-close-3 button or modal-bg-3 will close modal-3.

How can this code be made more optimized, dry and efficient to accomodate other modals as they are generated by the cms

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // When Text 1 is clicked, open modal-1
  $(document).on("click", "#company-article-summary-1", function() {
    $("#company-article-modal-1").addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-1").addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-1").addClass("show");
    $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });

  // When anchor link 1 is clicked, open modal-1
  $(document).on("click", "#company-article-cta-1", function() {
    $("#company-article-modal-1").addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-1").addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-1").addClass("show");
    $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });

  // When Text 2 is clicked, open modal-2
  $(document).on("click", "#company-article-summary-2", function() {
    $("#company-article-modal-2").addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-2").addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-2").addClass("show");
    $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });

  // When anchor link 2 is clicked, open modal-2
  $(document).on("click", "#company-article-cta-2", function() {
    $("#company-article-modal-2").addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-2").addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-2").addClass("show");
    $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });

  // When Text 3 is clicked, open modal-3
  $(document).on("click", "#company-article-summary-3", function() {
    $("#company-article-modal-3").addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-3").addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-3").addClass("show");
    $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });

  // When anchor link 3 is clicked, open modal-3
  $(document).on("click", "#company-article-cta-3", function() {
    $("#company-article-modal-3").addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-3").addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-3").addClass("show");
    $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });


  // When background of modal-1 is clicked, close modal-1
  $('#company-article-modal-1').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== this)
      return;

    $("#company-article-modal-1").removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-1").removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-1").removeClass("show");
    $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
  });

  // When close-button-1 of modal-1 is clicked, close modal-1
  $('#company-article-modal-close-vector-1').on('click', function() {
    $("#company-article-modal-1").removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-1").removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-1").removeClass("show");
    $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
  });

  // When background of modal-2 is clicked, close modal-2
  $('#company-article-modal-2').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== this)
      return;

    $("#company-article-modal-2").removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-2").removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-2").removeClass("show");
    $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
  });

  // When close-button-2 of modal-2 is clicked, close modal-2
  $('#company-article-modal-close-vector-2').on('click', function() {
    $("#company-article-modal-2").removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-2").removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-2").removeClass("show");
    $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
  });

  // When background of modal-3 is clicked, close modal-3
  $('#company-article-modal-3').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== this)
      return;

    $("#company-article-modal-3").removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-3").removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-3").removeClass("show");
    $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
  });

  // When close-button-3 of modal-3 is clicked, close modal-3
  $('#company-article-modal-close-vector-3').on('click', function() {
    $("#company-article-modal-3").removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-3").removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-3").removeClass("show");
    $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
  });
})
```

```css
.company-side-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.company-side-modal.show {
  z-index: 999999;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.company-side-modal-close {
  fill: #fff;
}

.company-side-modal-close-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-69px, 0);
}

.company-side-modal-close-container.show {
  transition-delay: .07s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.company-side-modal-bg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  perspective: 1000;
  opacity: 0;
}

.company-side-modal-bg.show {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  transition-delay: .07s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.company-side-modal-content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 160%;
  letter-spacing: .01em;
  color: #000;
}

.company-side-modal-content h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #84553a;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

@media only screen and min-width 1439px {
  .company-side-modal-content {
    width: 720px;
  }
}

@media only screen and max-width 1100px {
  .company-side-modal-bg {
    width: 65%;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close-container {
    left: 35%;
  }
}

@media only screen and max-width 769px {
  .company-side-modal-bg {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close {
    fill: #fff;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close-container {
    left: 13%;
  }
  .company-publications-bg {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and max-width 600px {
  .company-side-modal-bg {
    width: 90%;
    right: unset;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5vh;
  }
  .company-side-modal-content {
    max-height: 90vh;
  }
  .company-side-modal-content h2 {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close {
    fill: #84553a;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close-container {
    left: unset;
    transform: unset;
    right: calc(20px+5%);
    top: calc(40px+5vh);
    z-index: 99999999;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-xl pt-3 pt-xl-5 px-0">

      <!-- First-->
      <div class="row px-2 mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
          <p id="company-article-summary-1">Summary 1</p>
          <a id="company-article-cta-1">Cta 1</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal-1 -->
        <div class="company-side-modal" id="company-article-modal-1">
          <div class="company-side-modal-close-container" id="company-article-modal-close-1">
            <svg width="28" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="company-side-modal-close" id="company-article-modal-close-vector-1"><path d="M27.367.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.096 0L14 10.905 3.799.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.095 0 2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096L10.904 14 .635 24.201a2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096c.421.422.984.633 1.547.633s1.126-.211 1.548-.633L14 17.096l10.201 10.27c.422.423.985.634 1.548.634.563 0 1.125-.211 1.548-.633a2.208 2.208 0 000-3.096L17.096 14l10.27-10.201a2.295 2.295 0 000-3.166z"/></svg>
          </div>
          <div class="company-side-modal-bg bg-white" id="company-article-content-1">
            <div class="company-side-modal-content py-4 px-2 px-md-3 py-lg-5 px-lg-4 px-xl-5 p-xl-5">
              <h2>Modal Title 1</h2>
              <p>Modal Content 1</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Second -->
      <div class="row px-2 mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
          <p id="company-article-summary-2">Summary 2</p>
          <a id="company-article-cta-2">Cta 2</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal-2 -->
        <div class="company-side-modal" id="company-article-modal-2">
          <div class="company-side-modal-close-container" id="company-article-modal-close-2">
            <svg width="28" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="company-side-modal-close" id="company-article-modal-close-vector-2" id="company-article"><path d="M27.367.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.096 0L14 10.905 3.799.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.095 0 2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096L10.904 14 .635 24.201a2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096c.421.422.984.633 1.547.633s1.126-.211 1.548-.633L14 17.096l10.201 10.27c.422.423.985.634 1.548.634.563 0 1.125-.211 1.548-.633a2.208 2.208 0 000-3.096L17.096 14l10.27-10.201a2.295 2.295 0 000-3.166z"/></svg>
          </div>
          <div class="company-side-modal-bg bg-white" id="company-article-content-2">
            <div class="company-side-modal-content py-4 px-2 px-md-3 py-lg-5 px-lg-4 px-xl-5 p-xl-5">
              <h2>Modal Title 2</h2>
              <p>Modal Content 2</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Third -->
      <div class="row px-2 mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
          <p id="company-article-summary-3">Summary 3</p>
          <a id="company-article-cta-3">Cta 3</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal-3 -->
        <div class="company-side-modal" id="company-article-modal-3">
          <div class="company-side-modal-close-container" id="company-article-modal-close-3">
            <svg width="28" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="company-side-modal-close" id="company-article-modal-close-vector-3" id="company-article"><path d="M27.367.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.096 0L14 10.905 3.799.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.095 0 2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096L10.904 14 .635 24.201a2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096c.421.422.984.633 1.547.633s1.126-.211 1.548-.633L14 17.096l10.201 10.27c.422.423.985.634 1.548.634.563 0 1.125-.211 1.548-.633a2.208 2.208 0 000-3.096L17.096 14l10.27-10.201a2.295 2.295 0 000-3.166z"/></svg>
          </div>
          <div class="company-side-modal-bg bg-white" id="company-article-content-3">
            <div class="company-side-modal-content py-4 px-2 px-md-3 py-lg-5 px-lg-4 px-xl-5 p-xl-5">
              <h2>Modal Title 3</h2>
              <p>Modal Content 3</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: You said "...accomodate other modals as they are generated by the cms." Does this mean that it's not possible to alter the HTML?

Comment: @phuzi The html can be altered if it will work well and suit what I am trying to do. The code up there is just a simplified version of what I am trying to do. You can alter it. I will see if I can work around it. Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you have a loop?
```javascript
$('.company-side-modal').each(function (index) {
    $('#company-article-modal-' + index).on('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target !== this)
            return;

        $("#company-article-modal-" + index).removeClass("show");
        $("#company-article-modal-close-" + index).removeClass("show");
        $("#company-article-content-" + index).removeClass("show");
        $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can optimize your code by creating 2 arrays - one with the numbers (1, 2, 3) and one with your ids ("#company-article-summary-", "#company-article-summary-", "#company-article-cta-") and write function that will iterate through the two arrays and add the click listener to each combination

```
let arr = [1,2,3];
let ids = ["#company-article-summary-", "#company-article-summary-", "#company-article-cta-"];

arr.forEach((element, index) => {
    ids.forEach(e => {
        $(document).on("click", e + index, function() {
            $("#company-article-modal-" + index).addClass("show");
            $("#company-article-modal-close-" + index).addClass("show");
            $("#company-article-content-" + index).addClass("show");
            $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
          });

        $('#company-article-modal-' + index).on('click', function(e) {
            if (e.target !== this)
              return;
            $("#company-article-modal-" + index).removeClass("show");
            $("#company-article-modal-close-" + index).removeClass("show");
            $("#company-article-content-" + index).removeClass("show");
            $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
          });
        
          $('#company-article-modal-close-vector-' + index).on('click', function() {
            $("#company-article-modal-" + index).removeClass("show");
            $("#company-article-modal-close-" + index).removeClass("show");
            $("#company-article-content-" + index).removeClass("show");
            $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
          });

    })
})
```

If you are able to change your HTML code, add custom attribute to the elements containing your index and your JS code will contain only 2 click listeners

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('[id^=company-article-summary-],[id^=company-article-cta-]').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).data('value');
    $("#company-article-modal-" + index).addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-" + index).addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-" + index).addClass("show");
    $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  })

  $("[id^=company-article-modal-]").click(function(e) {
    let index = $(this).data('value');
    if (e.target !== this)
      return;
    $("#company-article-modal-" + index).removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-" + index).removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-" + index).removeClass("show");
    $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
  })


})
```

```css
.company-side-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.company-side-modal.show {
  z-index: 999999;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.company-side-modal-close {
  fill: #fff;
}

.company-side-modal-close-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-69px, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-xl pt-3 pt-xl-5 px-0">

  <!-- First-->
  <div class="row px-2 mb-5">
    <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
      <p id="company-article-summary-1" data-value="1">Summary 1</p>
      <a id="company-article-cta-1" data-value="1">Cta 1</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal-1 -->
    <div class="company-side-modal" id="company-article-modal-1" data-value="1">
      <div class="company-side-modal-close-container" id="company-article-modal-close-1">
        <svg width="28" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="company-side-modal-close" id="company-article-modal-close-vector-1"><path d="M27.367.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.096 0L14 10.905 3.799.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.095 0 2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096L10.904 14 .635 24.201a2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096c.421.422.984.633 1.547.633s1.126-.211 1.548-.633L14 17.096l10.201 10.27c.422.423.985.634 1.548.634.563 0 1.125-.211 1.548-.633a2.208 2.208 0 000-3.096L17.096 14l10.27-10.201a2.295 2.295 0 000-3.166z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="company-side-modal-bg bg-white" id="company-article-content-1">
        <div class="company-side-modal-content py-4 px-2 px-md-3 py-lg-5 px-lg-4 px-xl-5 p-xl-5">
          <h2>Modal Title 1</h2>
          <p>Modal Content 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Second -->
  <div class="row px-2 mb-5">
    <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
      <p id="company-article-summary-2" data-value="2">Summary 2</p>
      <a id="company-article-cta-2" data-value="2">Cta 2</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal-2 -->
    <div class="company-side-modal" id="company-article-modal-2" data-value="2">
      <div class="company-side-modal-close-container" id="company-article-modal-close-2">
        <svg width="28" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="company-side-modal-close" id="company-article-modal-close-vector-2" id="company-article"><path d="M27.367.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.096 0L14 10.905 3.799.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.095 0 2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096L10.904 14 .635 24.201a2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096c.421.422.984.633 1.547.633s1.126-.211 1.548-.633L14 17.096l10.201 10.27c.422.423.985.634 1.548.634.563 0 1.125-.211 1.548-.633a2.208 2.208 0 000-3.096L17.096 14l10.27-10.201a2.295 2.295 0 000-3.166z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="company-side-modal-bg bg-white" id="company-article-content-2">
        <div class="company-side-modal-content py-4 px-2 px-md-3 py-lg-5 px-lg-4 px-xl-5 p-xl-5">
          <h2>Modal Title 2</h2>
          <p>Modal Content 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Third -->
  <div class="row px-2 mb-5">
    <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
      <p id="company-article-summary-3" data-value="3">Summary 3</p>
      <a id="company-article-cta-3" data-value="3">Cta 3</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal-3 -->
    <div class="company-side-modal" id="company-article-modal-3" data-value="3">
      <div class="company-side-modal-close-container" id="company-article-modal-close-3">
        <svg width="28" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="company-side-modal-close" id="company-article-modal-close-vector-3" id="company-article"><path d="M27.367.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.096 0L14 10.905 3.799.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.095 0 2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096L10.904 14 .635 24.201a2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096c.421.422.984.633 1.547.633s1.126-.211 1.548-.633L14 17.096l10.201 10.27c.422.423.985.634 1.548.634.563 0 1.125-.211 1.548-.633a2.208 2.208 0 000-3.096L17.096 14l10.27-10.201a2.295 2.295 0 000-3.166z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="company-side-modal-bg bg-white" id="company-article-content-3">
        <div class="company-side-modal-content py-4 px-2 px-md-3 py-lg-5 px-lg-4 px-xl-5 p-xl-5">
          <h2>Modal Title 3</h2>
          <p>Modal Content 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What about the case where the number is more than 3 and can number to 100. 100 is just an example here. It could be more or less.

Comment: you can modify the **arr** array to whatever elements you want, but you should know that this is very complex when working with large data. Maybe it would be better if you write a click listener to paragraph containing the summary. Can you change the html?

Comment: Yes, the html can be changed to a better and more effective one

Comment: `each` is again iterating through all elements

Comment: But yes, we don't have to touch the html, we can get the last char of the id of the clicked element `$('[id^=company-article-summary-],[id^=company-article-cta-]').click(function(i) {
    let index = i.target.id.slice(i.target.id.length - 1) })`

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your repetitive code in `.forEach`, if new ones are to be added, you can just add the id to the array:

```js
let n = 3;
$(document).ready(function() {
  Array(n).fill(0).forEach(function(value, i) {
    i++;
    $(document).on("click", "#company-article-summary-" + i +", #company-article-cta-" + i, function() {
      $("#company-article-modal-" + i).addClass("show");
      $("#company-article-modal-close-" + i).addClass("show");
      $("#company-article-content-" + i).addClass("show");
      $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    });

    $('#company-article-modal-' + i + ', #company-article-modal-close-vector-' + i).on('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target.id.indexOf('modal') > -1 && e.target !== this)
        return;

      $("#company-article-modal-" + i).removeClass("show");
      $("#company-article-modal-close-" + i).removeClass("show");
      $("#company-article-content-" + i).removeClass("show");
      $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
    });
  });
});
```

```js
let n = 3;
$(document).ready(function() {
  Array(n).fill(0).forEach(function(value, i) {
    i++;
    $(document).on("click", "#company-article-summary-" + i +", #company-article-cta-" + i, function() {
      $("#company-article-modal-" + i).addClass("show");
      $("#company-article-modal-close-" + i).addClass("show");
      $("#company-article-content-" + i).addClass("show");
      $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    });

    $('#company-article-modal-' + i + ', #company-article-modal-close-vector-' + i).on('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target.id.indexOf('modal') > -1 && e.target !== this)
        return;

      $("#company-article-modal-" + i).removeClass("show");
      $("#company-article-modal-close-" + i).removeClass("show");
      $("#company-article-content-" + i).removeClass("show");
      $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.company-side-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.company-side-modal.show {
  z-index: 999999;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.company-side-modal-close {
  fill: #fff;
}

.company-side-modal-close-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-69px, 0);
}

.company-side-modal-close-container.show {
  transition-delay: .07s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.company-side-modal-bg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  perspective: 1000;
  opacity: 0;
}

.company-side-modal-bg.show {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  transition-delay: .07s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.company-side-modal-content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 160%;
  letter-spacing: .01em;
  color: #000;
}

.company-side-modal-content h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #84553a;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

@media only screen and min-width 1439px {
  .company-side-modal-content {
    width: 720px;
  }
}

@media only screen and max-width 1100px {
  .company-side-modal-bg {
    width: 65%;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close-container {
    left: 35%;
  }
}

@media only screen and max-width 769px {
  .company-side-modal-bg {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close {
    fill: #fff;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close-container {
    left: 13%;
  }
  .company-publications-bg {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and max-width 600px {
  .company-side-modal-bg {
    width: 90%;
    right: unset;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5vh;
  }
  .company-side-modal-content {
    max-height: 90vh;
  }
  .company-side-modal-content h2 {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close {
    fill: #84553a;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close-container {
    left: unset;
    transform: unset;
    right: calc(20px+5%);
    top: calc(40px+5vh);
    z-index: 99999999;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-xl pt-3 pt-xl-5 px-0">

  <!-- First-->
  <div class="row px-2 mb-5">
    <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
      <p id="company-article-summary-1">Summary 1</p>
      <a id="company-article-cta-1">Cta 1</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal-1 -->
    <div class="company-side-modal" id="company-article-modal-1">
      <div class="company-side-modal-close-container" id="company-article-modal-close-1">
        <svg width="28" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="company-side-modal-close" id="company-article-modal-close-vector-1"><path d="M27.367.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.096 0L14 10.905 3.799.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.095 0 2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096L10.904 14 .635 24.201a2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096c.421.422.984.633 1.547.633s1.126-.211 1.548-.633L14 17.096l10.201 10.27c.422.423.985.634 1.548.634.563 0 1.125-.211 1.548-.633a2.208 2.208 0 000-3.096L17.096 14l10.27-10.201a2.295 2.295 0 000-3.166z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="company-side-modal-bg bg-white" id="company-article-content-1">
        <div class="company-side-modal-content py-4 px-2 px-md-3 py-lg-5 px-lg-4 px-xl-5 p-xl-5">
          <h2>Modal Title 1</h2>
          <p>Modal Content 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Second -->
  <div class="row px-2 mb-5">
    <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
      <p id="company-article-summary-2">Summary 2</p>
      <a id="company-article-cta-2">Cta 2</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal-2 -->
    <div class="company-side-modal" id="company-article-modal-2">
      <div class="company-side-modal-close-container" id="company-article-modal-close-2">
        <svg width="28" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="company-side-modal-close" id="company-article-modal-close-vector-2" id="company-article"><path d="M27.367.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.096 0L14 10.905 3.799.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.095 0 2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096L10.904 14 .635 24.201a2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096c.421.422.984.633 1.547.633s1.126-.211 1.548-.633L14 17.096l10.201 10.27c.422.423.985.634 1.548.634.563 0 1.125-.211 1.548-.633a2.208 2.208 0 000-3.096L17.096 14l10.27-10.201a2.295 2.295 0 000-3.166z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="company-side-modal-bg bg-white" id="company-article-content-2">
        <div class="company-side-modal-content py-4 px-2 px-md-3 py-lg-5 px-lg-4 px-xl-5 p-xl-5">
          <h2>Modal Title 2</h2>
          <p>Modal Content 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Third -->
  <div class="row px-2 mb-5">
    <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
      <p id="company-article-summary-3">Summary 3</p>
      <a id="company-article-cta-3">Cta 3</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal-3 -->
    <div class="company-side-modal" id="company-article-modal-3">
      <div class="company-side-modal-close-container" id="company-article-modal-close-3">
        <svg width="28" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="company-side-modal-close" id="company-article-modal-close-vector-3" id="company-article"><path d="M27.367.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.096 0L14 10.905 3.799.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.095 0 2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096L10.904 14 .635 24.201a2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096c.421.422.984.633 1.547.633s1.126-.211 1.548-.633L14 17.096l10.201 10.27c.422.423.985.634 1.548.634.563 0 1.125-.211 1.548-.633a2.208 2.208 0 000-3.096L17.096 14l10.27-10.201a2.295 2.295 0 000-3.166z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="company-side-modal-bg bg-white" id="company-article-content-3">
        <div class="company-side-modal-content py-4 px-2 px-md-3 py-lg-5 px-lg-4 px-xl-5 p-xl-5">
          <h2>Modal Title 3</h2>
          <p>Modal Content 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

EDIT

More optimized code (thanks [Sara Stoimenovska](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14492228/sara-stoimenovska)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^=company-article-summary-]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).data('value', i + 1);
  });
  $('[id^=company-article-cta-]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).data('value', i + 1);
  });
  $('[id^=company-article-modal-close-vector-]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).data('value', i + 1);
  });
  $('[id^=company-article-summary-],[id^=company-article-cta-]').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).data('value');
    $("#company-article-modal-" + index).addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-" + index).addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-" + index).addClass("show");
    $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  })

  $("[id^=company-article-modal-]").click(function(e) {
    let index = $(this).find('[id^=company-article-modal-close-vector-]').data('value');
    if (e.target.id.indexOf('vector') > -1 && e.target !== this)
      return;
    $("#company-article-modal-" + index).removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-" + index).removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-" + index).removeClass("show");
    $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^=company-article-summary-]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).data('value', i + 1);
  });
  $('[id^=company-article-cta-]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).data('value', i + 1);
  });
  $('[id^=company-article-modal-close-vector-]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).data('value', i + 1);
  });
  $('[id^=company-article-summary-],[id^=company-article-cta-]').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).data('value');
    $("#company-article-modal-" + index).addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-" + index).addClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-" + index).addClass("show");
    $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  })

  $("[id^=company-article-modal-]").click(function(e) {
    let index = $(this).find('[id^=company-article-modal-close-vector-]').data('value');
    if (e.target.id.indexOf('vector') > -1 && e.target !== this)
      return;
    $("#company-article-modal-" + index).removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-modal-close-" + index).removeClass("show");
    $("#company-article-content-" + index).removeClass("show");
    $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
  });
});
```

```css
.company-side-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.company-side-modal.show {
  z-index: 999999;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.company-side-modal-close {
  fill: #fff;
}

.company-side-modal-close-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-69px, 0);
}

.company-side-modal-close-container.show {
  transition-delay: .07s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.company-side-modal-bg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  perspective: 1000;
  opacity: 0;
}

.company-side-modal-bg.show {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  transition-delay: .07s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.company-side-modal-content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 160%;
  letter-spacing: .01em;
  color: #000;
}

.company-side-modal-content h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #84553a;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

@media only screen and min-width 1439px {
  .company-side-modal-content {
    width: 720px;
  }
}

@media only screen and max-width 1100px {
  .company-side-modal-bg {
    width: 65%;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close-container {
    left: 35%;
  }
}

@media only screen and max-width 769px {
  .company-side-modal-bg {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close {
    fill: #fff;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close-container {
    left: 13%;
  }
  .company-publications-bg {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and max-width 600px {
  .company-side-modal-bg {
    width: 90%;
    right: unset;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5vh;
  }
  .company-side-modal-content {
    max-height: 90vh;
  }
  .company-side-modal-content h2 {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close {
    fill: #84553a;
  }
  .company-side-modal-close-container {
    left: unset;
    transform: unset;
    right: calc(20px+5%);
    top: calc(40px+5vh);
    z-index: 99999999;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-xl pt-3 pt-xl-5 px-0">

  <!-- First-->
  <div class="row px-2 mb-5">
    <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
      <p id="company-article-summary-1">Summary 1</p>
      <a id="company-article-cta-1">Cta 1</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal-1 -->
    <div class="company-side-modal" id="company-article-modal-1">
      <div class="company-side-modal-close-container" id="company-article-modal-close-1">
        <svg width="28" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="company-side-modal-close" id="company-article-modal-close-vector-1"><path d="M27.367.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.096 0L14 10.905 3.799.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.095 0 2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096L10.904 14 .635 24.201a2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096c.421.422.984.633 1.547.633s1.126-.211 1.548-.633L14 17.096l10.201 10.27c.422.423.985.634 1.548.634.563 0 1.125-.211 1.548-.633a2.208 2.208 0 000-3.096L17.096 14l10.27-10.201a2.295 2.295 0 000-3.166z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="company-side-modal-bg bg-white" id="company-article-content-1">
        <div class="company-side-modal-content py-4 px-2 px-md-3 py-lg-5 px-lg-4 px-xl-5 p-xl-5">
          <h2>Modal Title 1</h2>
          <p>Modal Content 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Second -->
  <div class="row px-2 mb-5">
    <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
      <p id="company-article-summary-2">Summary 2</p>
      <a id="company-article-cta-2">Cta 2</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal-2 -->
    <div class="company-side-modal" id="company-article-modal-2">
      <div class="company-side-modal-close-container" id="company-article-modal-close-2">
        <svg width="28" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="company-side-modal-close" id="company-article-modal-close-vector-2" id="company-article"><path d="M27.367.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.096 0L14 10.905 3.799.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.095 0 2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096L10.904 14 .635 24.201a2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096c.421.422.984.633 1.547.633s1.126-.211 1.548-.633L14 17.096l10.201 10.27c.422.423.985.634 1.548.634.563 0 1.125-.211 1.548-.633a2.208 2.208 0 000-3.096L17.096 14l10.27-10.201a2.295 2.295 0 000-3.166z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="company-side-modal-bg bg-white" id="company-article-content-2">
        <div class="company-side-modal-content py-4 px-2 px-md-3 py-lg-5 px-lg-4 px-xl-5 p-xl-5">
          <h2>Modal Title 2</h2>
          <p>Modal Content 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Third -->
  <div class="row px-2 mb-5">
    <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
      <p id="company-article-summary-3">Summary 3</p>
      <a id="company-article-cta-3">Cta 3</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal-3 -->
    <div class="company-side-modal" id="company-article-modal-3">
      <div class="company-side-modal-close-container" id="company-article-modal-close-3">
        <svg width="28" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="company-side-modal-close" id="company-article-modal-close-vector-3" id="company-article"><path d="M27.367.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.096 0L14 10.905 3.799.633a2.208 2.208 0 00-3.095 0 2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096L10.904 14 .635 24.201a2.208 2.208 0 000 3.096c.421.422.984.633 1.547.633s1.126-.211 1.548-.633L14 17.096l10.201 10.27c.422.423.985.634 1.548.634.563 0 1.125-.211 1.548-.633a2.208 2.208 0 000-3.096L17.096 14l10.27-10.201a2.295 2.295 0 000-3.166z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="company-side-modal-bg bg-white" id="company-article-content-3">
        <div class="company-side-modal-content py-4 px-2 px-md-3 py-lg-5 px-lg-4 px-xl-5 p-xl-5">
          <h2>Modal Title 3</h2>
          <p>Modal Content 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to optimize it further to work for any amount of numbers even if they number up to 100 without writing out the numbers 1, 2,3,4,5,....,100. 100 is just an example here. The number is unknown

Comment: You can do the loop base on actual objects. jQuery has a [method](https://api.jquery.com/each/) for this.

Comment: @Idris you can use `Array(3).fill(0)` as above,please check updated code. Now you can just mention number of modals

Comment: Thank you @shrys. I will use that

Comment: This is not an optimized solution. If you have 100 items, it will iterate all 100 items and add click listener to each one of them (3 in total = 300 click listeners) even if you don't use them at all

Comment: @SaraStoimenovska yep, your solution is way better. I would urge OP to refer and use your answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to wrap the repeated code in a function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function showContent(selector) {
    $(selector).addClass("show");
    $("body,html").css("overflow", "hidden");
  }

  function hideContent(selector) {
    $(selector).removeClass("show");
    $("body,html").css("overflow", "");
  }

  $(document).on("click", "#company-article-summary-1,#company-article-cta-1", function () {
    showContent("#company-article-modal-1,#company-article-modal-close-1,#company-article-content-1");
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#company-article-modal-1,#company-article-modal-close-vector-1", function () {
    hideContent("#company-article-modal-1,#company-article-modal-close-1,#company-article-content-1");
  });
});

  // repeat for 2, 3
```

Then, you should follow up by giving the `summary`, `cta`, `modal` and `modal-close` elements each a class name so you can target them with a simpler selector, such as

```
$(document).on("click", ".article-summary,.article-content", function () {
```

Then, considering how your markup is laid out, it might be better to target the modal/close/content elements by looking them up in the element hierarchy instead; something like

```
showContent($(this).closest(".row").find(".modal,.modal-close,.article"));
```